# Can start sentence with "Allowing to"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

Can I start a sentence as follows?

> Allowing to detect only circular shape objects, objects, classified mistakenly as trees, can be avoided from the modelling process.

or may be can we write it as:

> Objects, classified mistakenly as trees, can be avoided from the modelling process allowing to detect only circular shape objects.

Please correct me in this.

Comment: Writing advice/critique requests are off topic per the site [info].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better way of putting it:

Allowing detection of only circular shape objects, objects mistakenly classified as trees, can be avoided from the modelling process.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace "Allowing to" with "In order to". Your second example would be better as follows.

> Objects, classified mistakenly as trees, can be avoided from the
>   modelling process *in order to* detect only circular shape objects.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Thats mean the 1st one is incorrect or meaning less?

Comment: the first one is correct, but not as "elegant"

Comment: With the first one, the reader does get to understand the context until 2/3rds through the sentence. That's why the format suggested here is better.  Also the inclusion of "... objects, objects, ..." in your first format is hard on the reader: one tends to have to read it *twice* before understanding it.